# (jQuery) How to avoid registering multiple click events under another click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have 2 click events under one click event for a Delete jQuery dialog popup. What it is doing right now that when I click delete a Course, it opens up a dialog popup, and I can either click "Yes" to confirm deletion, or "No" to close the dialog box.

It is working, but when I log the "No" button and click it twice, the Developer Tools Console shows I have clicked it 3 times. Like each click after the first one, the console doubles it. I am not being able to work out on how to separate the click events and still work inside of the same dialog popup box?

```
<div class="table-content">

..........
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CourseID }, new {   @class = "deletebtn", @id = item.CourseID })

</div>

<div id="dialog" title="Delete Department" style="display: none">
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this Course?</p>
    <button id="confirm-deletion">Yes</button>
    <button id="abort-deletion">No</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".deletebtn").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#dialog').dialog();

            var btnobj = $(this);
            var id = btnobj[0].id;

            $('#confirm-deletion').on("click", function () {

                var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
                var data = { id: id, __RequestVerificationToken: token };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Delete","Course")",
                    data: data,
                    //ajaxasync: true,
                    success: function () {
                        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                        $('div.table-content').empty().load(' .table-content');
                        //console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("failed");
                    }
                });
            });
            $('#abort-deletion').on("click", function () {

                console.log("NoClick");

                $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a click event *inside* of a click event.  This will, as you've found, add a new event with every click.  Create it *once* when the page loads:

```
$(function () {

    $(".deletebtn").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog').dialog();

        var btnobj = $(this);
        var id = btnobj[0].id;

        // don't create click events here

    });

    $('#confirm-deletion').on("click", function () {
        //...
    });


    $('#abort-deletion').on("click", function () {
        //...
    });
});
```

If the problem you encounter is that the elements aren't yet defined when the page loads, you can bind the event to a common parent and use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on("click", '#confirm-deletion', function () {
    //...
});
```

Comment: I think it is the latter part. Which one would be the parent button? The `(".deletebtn").on ("click")` ?

Comment: @StraightUp: I don't know what you mean by "parent button".  But what happens when you define these click handlers on their own instead of repeatedly defining them with every click?  The code in the question doesn't imply that these elements are being dynamically created, that's simply a common reason for doing what you were trying to do.

Comment: When I said the "parent button", I was referring to what you had mentioned, "common parent". Sorry, as I am new to jQuery, I am unfamiliar with a lot of the terms. ...But as of right now when I separate each click event under one function, the "No" button works fine as it just closes out the dialog box. But the "Yes" button is not working to delete the item when I confirm it.

Comment: @StraightUp: Time to debug a little to narrow down what "not working" means.  You can toss in a couple `console.log()` statements to help with that easily enough.  For example, when you bind the other click events, are those elements found on the page at all at that time?  If they're being added by AJAX then that's where the latter part of my answer becomes helpful.  Or if the elements *are* found and they *are* handling the click events, what inside those events is failing?  "Not working" is going to require providing a *complete* replication of the problem, but a little debugging helps more.

Comment: Not working meant it does not delete the record I want to delete upon clicking "Yes". The console logs it as failed.

Comment: But thanks, I am going to debug it to see where the issue is coming from.

Comment: @StraightUp: In that case the button click event handler *is* working.  You'll need to determine what's failing in the AJAX request and why.

Comment: I have a question about binding the event. When you have `(document).on("click", '#confirm-deletion', function () {` , is the `document` referring to the DOM? And do I put the other 2 click events inside that common parent ?

Comment: @StraightUp: The `document` is the top-level element in the DOM.  Any "common parent" HTML element will do.  Take a look at the link about event delegation.  Basically you can use any HTML element which won't dynamically change and will contain all of the dynamically added/removed target elements.  `document` is always guaranteed to do that, but could be overkill in some cases.  "Common parent" simply refers to any HTML element which contains all of the target elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
let clickRegistered = false;

  $(".deletebtn").on("click", function (e) {
       if(!clickRegistered){
            clickRegistered = true;
            //... registerComponents/call functions ...
       }
  });
```

`clickRegistered` is used to make sure that function body wil execute only once.